# How to force MATLAB function area to hold on in figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm working on this function which gets axis handler and data, and is supposed to plot it correctly in the axis. The function is called in for loop. It's supposed to draw the multiple data in one figure. My resulted figure is shown below.

[image: power spectrum graphs]

There are only two correctly plotted graphs (those with four colors). Others miss areas plotted before the final area (red area is the last plotted area in each graph). But the script is same for every axis. So where can be the mistake? The whole function is written below.

```
function [] = powerSpectrumSmooth(axis,signal,fs)

N= length(signal);
samplesPer1Hz = N/fs;
delta = int16(3.5*samplesPer1Hz); %last sample of delta frequncies
theta = int16(7.5*samplesPer1Hz); %last sample of theta frequncies
alpha = int16(13*samplesPer1Hz); %last sample of alpha frequncies
beta = int16(30*samplesPer1Hz); %last sample of beta frequncies

x=fft(double(signal));
powerSpectrum = 20*log10(abs(real(x)));
smoothPS=smooth(powerSpectrum,51);

PSmin=min(powerSpectrum(1:beta));

y1=[(smoothPS(1:delta)); zeros(beta-delta,1)+PSmin];
y2=[zeros(delta-1,1)+PSmin; (smoothPS(delta:theta)); zeros(beta-theta,1)+PSmin];
y3=[zeros(theta-1,1)+PSmin; (smoothPS(theta:alpha)); zeros(beta-alpha,1)+PSmin];
y4=[zeros(alpha-1,1)+PSmin; (smoothPS(alpha:beta))];


 a1=area(axis,1:beta,y1);
 set(a1,'FaceColor','yellow')
 hold on

 a2=area(axis,1:beta,y2);
 set(a2,'FaceColor','blue')

 a3=area(axis,1:beta,y3);
 set(a3,'FaceColor','green')

 a4=area(axis,1:beta,y4);
 set(a4,'FaceColor','red')
```

---

ADDED

And here is the function which calls the function above.

```
function [] = drawPowerSpectrum(axesContainer,dataContainer,fs)

size = length(axesContainer);

for l=1:size

    powerSpectrumSmooth(axesContainer{l},dataContainer{l},fs)

    set(axesContainer{l},'XTickLabel','')
    set(axesContainer{l},'YTickLabel','')

    uistack(axesContainer{l}, 'top');

end
```

---

ADDED 29th July

Here is a script which reproduces the error, so you can run it in your computer. Before running it again you might need to clear variables.

```
len = 9;

axesContainer = cell(len,1);
x = [0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.7];
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.7];

figure(1)

for i=1:len
    axesContainer{i} = axes('Position',[x(i),y(i),0.2,0.2]);
end

dataContainer = cell(len,1);
N = 1500;

for i=1:len
        dataContainer{i} = rand(1,N)*100;
end

for l=1:len

    y1=[(dataContainer{l}(1:N/4)) zeros(1,3*N/4)];
    y2=[zeros(1,N/4) (dataContainer{l}(N/4+1:(2*N/4))) zeros(1,2*N/4)];
    y3=[zeros(1,2*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(2*N/4+1:3*N/4)) zeros(1,N/4)];
    y4=[zeros(1,3*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(3*N/4+1:N))];

    axes=axesContainer{l};

    a1=area(axes,1:N,y1);
    set(a1,'FaceColor','yellow')
    hold on
    a2=area(axes,1:N,y2);
    set(a2,'FaceColor','blue')
    hold on
    a3=area(axes,1:N,y3);
    set(a3,'FaceColor','green')
    hold on
    a4=area(axes,1:N,y4);
    set(a4,'FaceColor','red')

    set(axes,'XTickLabel','')
    set(axes,'YTickLabel','')

end
```

My result of this script is plotted below:

[image]

Again only one picture contains all areas.

Comment: please show your entire code & what will happen if you add `hold off` into the last line of the function and move `hold on` above `a1=...`?

Comment: Wow, what do you mean by "entire code"? It's like 6 functions involved. This one is the only important. I may add the one with loop.

When I add hold off at the end, nothing changes. Same with the hold on above a1.

Comment: Try to post a MVCE that reproduces this efect with fake data, so we can copy the code, try it and debug it. else it will be very hard to help!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't know what MVCE means, but I think I undrestood what you meant. The script is added. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Do you need to create the axes that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do what I needed.

```
len = 8;

axesContainer = cell(len,1);
x = [0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4];
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7];

figure(1)

for i=1:len
    axesContainer{i} = axes('Position',[x(i),y(i),0.2,0.2]);
end

dataContainer = cell(len,1);
N = 1500;

for i=1:len
        dataContainer{i} = rand(1,N)*100;
end

for l=1:len

    y1=[(dataContainer{l}(1:N/4)) zeros(1,3*N/4)];
    y2=[zeros(1,N/4) (dataContainer{l}(N/4+1:(2*N/4))) zeros(1,2*N/4)];
    y3=[zeros(1,2*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(2*N/4+1:3*N/4)) zeros(1,N/4)];
    y4=[zeros(1,3*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(3*N/4+1:N))];

    axes=axesContainer{l};

    Y=[y1',y2',y3',y4'];

    a=area(axes,Y);

    set(axes,'XTickLabel','')
    set(axes,'YTickLabel','')

end
```

The area is supposed to work with matrices like this. The tricky part is, that the signal in every next column is not plotted absolutely, but relatively to the data in previous column. That means, if at time 1 the data in first column has value 1 and data in second column has value 4, the second column data is ploted at value 5. Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that every call to `plot(axes,data)` deletes whatever was written in `axes`.

**Important note:** Do not use a variable name the same as a function. Do not call something `sin` ,`plot` or `axes`!! I changed it to `axs`.

To solve the problem I just used the classic `subplot` instead of creating the axes as you did:

```
len = 9;

axesContainer = cell(len,1);
x = [0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.7];
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.7];

figure(1)


dataContainer = cell(len,1);
N = 1500;

for i=1:len
        dataContainer{i} = rand(1,N)*100;
end

for l=1:len

    y1=[(dataContainer{l}(1:N/4)) zeros(1,3*N/4)];
    y2=[zeros(1,N/4) (dataContainer{l}(N/4+1:(2*N/4))) zeros(1,2*N/4)];
    y3=[zeros(1,2*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(2*N/4+1:3*N/4)) zeros(1,N/4)];
    y4=[zeros(1,3*N/4) (dataContainer{l}(3*N/4+1:N))];

    axs=subplot(3,3,l);

    a1=area(axs,1:N,y1);
    set(a1,'FaceColor','yellow')
    hold on
    a2=area(axs,1:N,y2);
    set(a2,'FaceColor','blue')
    hold on
    a3=area(axs,1:N,y3);
    set(a3,'FaceColor','green')
    hold on
    a4=area(axs,1:N,y4);
    set(a4,'FaceColor','red')
 
    set(axs,'XTickLabel','')
    set(axs,'YTickLabel','')
    axis tight % this is to beautify it.
end
```

[image]

As far as I know, you can still save the `axs` variable in an `axescontainer` and then modify the properties you want (like location).

Comment: It does work, but I'm not sure whether the right answer for question like "how to force function XYZ to do something" is "by not using the function".

Comment: @user50222 Can't agree more with you. Its just, it doesnt seem you can forece fucntion XYZ to do what you want :(